# BeagleBone Black: USB errors when using Webcam

Tags: linux, webcam, beagleboneblack

I want to use my [BeagleBone Black](http://beagleboard.org/black) to setup  [a Webcam](http://hoeckerson.de/notes/2014/08/beaglebone-as-a-webcam/). I installed `fswebcam` and configured it to take a picture every 10 seconds. However, the BeagleBone produces the following errors in `dmesg` every few minutes:

```
dmesg | tail -n 3
-> [  220.258214] musb_host_rx 1762: Rx interrupt with no errors or packet!
-> [  490.302277] musb_ep_program 896: broken !rx_reinit, ep13 csr 0003
-> [  490.308731] musb_host_rx 1762: Rx interrupt with no errors or packet!
```

After a few hours (at most!) it freezes up completely and I have to power-cycle it. (The power-button doesn't shut it down anymore.)

This error has been bugging me for weeks. I tried all possible configurations I can think of:

- Three different Beaglebones: Two revision A5A and one revision A5C
- Five different Power supplies: Three via USB, two via Barrel connector
- Three different Webcams: One Logitech C920, one HP 3100, one no-name El-Cheapo
- Two different Linux distributions: The current [ArmHF Ubuntu 14.04](http://s3.armhf.com/dist/bone/ubuntu-trusty-14.04-rootfs-3.14.4.1-bone-armhf.com.tar.xz) distribution and the [currently linked debian](http://debian.beagleboard.org/images/bone-debian-7.5-2014-05-14-2gb.img.xz) distribution on the official "[latest images](http://beagleboard.org/latest-images)" page (which is a few months behind!). I updated the Kernel of the latter image using the appropriate script in /opt/scripts - but that did not help either.
- I installed `fswebcam` through package managers and compiled it from source.

For `fswebcam` I tried various config files (including delays and skipping images). One example config file that I tried:

```
background
loop 10
resolution 1920x1080
scale 1280x720
title "test-picture"
timestamp "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S (%Z)"
jpeg 70
banner-colour #FF000000
line-colour #FF000000
no-shadow
save ~/test-picture.jpg
```

How can I keep my BeagleBone Black from crashing?

**Update**: I finally got it to work using a (borrowed) Rev A5C BeagleBone. I still get the dmesg errors, but at least the BeagleBone does not crash. I currently suspect a hardware issue on the RevA5B BeagleBone.

Comment: If you have the source of these applications, you could try to debug them. Put debug output in different methods, or even better, all around your code. Check which was the last output you got before the crash and which was the first you didn' get anymore. Narrow it down to see what causes this behaviour.